# why is "onpressed" is not working when clicking on the "title" but works when clicked on "leading" property?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

my objective is this. When clicked on the title property I want to change its property.

I have attached a gif of the problem I am facing.
[code demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvdD4.gif)

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Icon _searchIcon = Icon(Icons.search, size: 40);
  Icon _searchIcon2 = Icon(Icons.alarm, size: 40);

  void _searchPressed() {
    setState(() {
      if (this._searchIcon.icon == Icons.search) {
        this._searchIcon = _searchIcon2;
      } else {
        this._searchIcon = Icon(Icons.search);}});}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: _searchIcon,
          onPressed: _searchPressed,
        ),
        title: IconButton(
          icon: _searchIcon,
          onPressed: () => _searchPressed,),),);}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As what @CopsOnRoad have suggested, it should be either

```
onPressed: _searchPressed
```

or

```
onPressed: () => _searchPressed()
```

The reason why `onPressed: () => _searchPressed` didn't work is beacause the anonymous function you just passed into `onPressed` property is only returning `_searchPressed` blueprint without actually running the function. So in essence, it's not doing anything other than just giving the `onPressed` property the blueprint of that `_searchPressed` function itself.

Hence why the code below work, because you actually put the function `_searchPressed` into the `onPressed` property correctly

```
onPressed: _searchPressed
```

Answer (score 0):

In your title's `IconButton`,

Instead of

```dart
onPressed: () => _searchPressed
```

Use

```dart
onPressed: _searchPressed
```

or

```dart
onPressed: () => _searchPressed()
```